# Attempted JS injection in form on website? - alert('TK00000025')

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I just received 20 submissions in a form hosted on my website within 2 minutes. The only field that is filled in says `alert('TK00000025')` and each submission increases this number up to `alert('TK00000036')`. The field switches between forms, so one form has this in the name section with the next form having it in the email section. After this, there are four blank entries.

What is this and why did it happen? Is there anything I should do to prevent it?

Comment: It's an automated cross-site scripting attack against your site. I'd be checking to make sure it wasn't successful, but if your website properly sanitizes outputs you don't need to worry.

Comment: Perhaps something like recaptcha can help.

Comment: Thank you both, this is very helpful to know.

Comment: also not a bad idea to protect your system at TCP level like it is described here (although there weren't as much requests this time, but I would check it for future): http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139285/limit-max-connections-per-ip-address-and-new-connections-per-second-with-iptable

Comment: I understand now that it is an attempted hack, but could someone also explain what it is trying to do? I would like to understand what TK00000025 does in more detail.

Comment: My first guess would be that this is a random string not likely to be entered by a user. If the "success" event/page/whatever that loads after form is submitted causes "tkxxx" to appear in a JavaScript alert, then the attacker knows that they can run any JavaScript that they please on your site, potentially to you when you are viewing submissions (and logged into the site). Thus, xss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general:

1) Never Insert Untrusted Data Except in Allowed Locations

2) HTML Escape Before Inserting Untrusted Data into HTML Element Content

3) Attribute Escape Before Inserting Untrusted Data into HTML Common Attributes

4) JavaScript Escape Before Inserting Untrusted Data into JavaScript Data Values

5) HTML escape JSON values in an HTML context and read the data with JSON.parse

- JSON entity encoding
- HTML entity encoding

6) CSS Escape And Strictly Validate Before Inserting Untrusted Data into HTML Style Property Values

7) URL Escape Before Inserting Untrusted Data into HTML URL Parameter Values

8) Sanitize HTML Markup with a Library Designed for the Job

9) Prevent DOM-based XSS

If you do the fallowing I am sure you are pretty much safe as it is.

reference: [Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)